# Why jquery "change" event does not work in my example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a `[name="tip"]` has the first value, display a specific element, otherwise it would display another element.

Both elements have the `display:none` property. When I load the page I check the select value and fadeIn the desired element automatically.

Everything works fine except when I try to change the selected option: nothing happens. I added both javascript `onchange` to that item and jquery `.change()` and nothing happens. Can you tell me why it does not work in my example?

```
<form id="fm-account-properties-tab" method="POST">
<table width="300px" style="margin-top:10px;" align="center" >

    <tr>
        
        <td align="left">
        <select class="easyui-combobox" name="tip" style="width:200px;" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true" onchange="changeType();">
                    <option value="l1">l1</option>
                    <option value="l2">l2</option>
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $('[name="tip"]').val('<?php echo $a['tip'];?>');
                        });
                    </script>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="l1" style="display:none">

        <td align="left">
        <select class="easyui-combobox" name="l1"  style="width:200px;" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true">
                    
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="l2" style="display:none">

        <td align="left">
        <select class="easyui-combobox" name="l2"  style="width:200px;" class="easyui-validatebox">
                    
                    
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<script>
function changeType()
{

if($('[name="tip"]').val()=='l1')
    {
    $('#l1').fadeIn();
    $('#l2').hide();
    }
else
    {
    $('#l2').fadeIn();
    $('#l1').hide();
    }
}



$(document).ready( function () {
        
        changeType();

            $('[name="tip"]').change(function(){ alert('1');});//it never alerts me
    });
```

Comment: How did you declare your `DOCTYPE` ? Even though it's not directly related to your issue, `id` attributes beginning by numbers are **not** valid in HTML4. They are in HTML5 though.

Comment: How many elements are there with a name of `tip`? There are far too many questions raised by this question...

Comment: its not about id. i posted here numeric id , tho they are strings

Comment: one element with name tip...the main select

Comment: Just a small comment: why do you end your id's with underscores? I know it is allowed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html but why do you do that?

Comment: Can you post the HTML too, please?

Comment: i don't know,it's my way of coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.on` for newer jQuery versions (jQuery > 1.7.x [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/))

```
function changeType() {
    if ($('[name="tip"]').val() == '___') {
        $('#1').fadeIn();
        $('#2').hide();
    } else {
        $('#2').fadeIn();
        $('#1').hide();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    changeType();
    $('select[name="tip"]').on('change', function() {
        changeType();
    });
});
```

you have a double class attribute on your select.

here is a working sample http://jsfiddle.net/tvhKH/

Comment: used...yet,nothing happened:P
will post the html too

Comment: added html,hope it's better now

Comment: Perhaps in the www.jeasyui.com library. remove the class and add this in the js: `$('select[name="tip"]').combobox({  
    onSelect: function(rec){ changeType(); }
    });

Comment: thanks,that finally did the trick.thanks a lot,i'll set your answer as accepted:)

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use `js error event` to figure out the error in that code. E.g, `<script> try
{....all your codes here...}
catch(err)
{alert("THE ERRor" + err.message);} </script>`. These code will alert your error and the exact point it occurs. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should try to add a

```
console.log("It works");
```

or a

```
alert("It works")
```

in your method so you know if it is actualy called.

Then I think the issue may come from FadeIn() only works on elements with css {display: none} and visibility different of 'hidden', so are you sure your elements are ? In doubt, you may replace

```
.fadeIn();
```

by

```
.css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn(); // hide() does the same as display: none
```

Then please let me know if you have more information after doing that.

Comment: it seems it never reaches 
$('[name="tip"]').change( function(e) {
    alert("It works");
}); 

in there...i never get that alert,that's why i said it's about the change method

Comment: are you using jquery 1.7 or newer?